# add minus key to TEdit keyboard

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

This isn't a big deal but i thought i'd ask in case the solution is straight forward.  I'm using a TEdit box for user to input a decimal number. I'd like to have a minus key so they can enter negative number, but i'd prefer not to use the alphanumeric keyboards, i'd prefer a nice clean keyboard like the keyboard below (that is what i get on iOS with my `TEdit` box `KeyboardType` set to `DecimalNumberPad`.

[image]

Is there a way to get a keyboard that is limited to just numbers, decimal, and backspace but also with **minus key**?  I have a work-around to let them change sign on the number.  I'm just wondering if a simple solution exists that would look cleaner.

Comment: Does `KeyboardType=NumbersAndPunctuation` contain a minus symbol? I know Android has a `numberSigned` inputType defined for allowing decimal numbers with leading sign, but I don't think FireMonkey has a mapping to that exact keyboard type.

Comment: Yes, but i'm wanting a simpler keyboard like shown in the picture above - but with a minus key or maybe a +/- toggle.

Comment: like I said, I don't think you can get this result using FireMonkey alone. You will likely have to access the underlying keyboard UI control directly and use OS APIs to manipulate it as needed.